# Run phpunit tests by testcase class that they extend

Tags: php, phpunit

I want to separate my tests in unit and integration tests and have an abstract TestCase class for each, e.g. `UnitTestCase` and `IntegrationTestCase`.

Is there a nice way to run only those tests that extend `UnitTestCase` without giving a `@group unit` annotation to each of these test classes?

The [phpunit documentation](https://phpunit.readthedocs.io/en/8.1/extending-phpunit.html#subclass-phpunit-framework-testcase) is very sparse when describing subclassing. Also a google search didn't turn up any useful results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. Either use the `@group` annotation for this or, better IMO, have a `tests/unit` directory for unit tests as well as a `tests/integration` directory for integration tests and then define two test suites in `phpunit.xml`. By default, both will be run. Using `--testsuite` you can then filter based on the test suite name.